# How to convert bitmatrix into bitmap?

Tags: java, android, barcode, zxing, qr-code

The ZXing library's [`Writer.encode()`](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs) function returns a `BitMatrix` object.  How does one convert that to a standard java `Bitmap` object so it can be used as the source of an `ImageView` in Android?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
writeToFile(BitMatrix matrix, String format, File file)
```

thsi method will write the **BitMatrix** into a file, now you can decode this file using

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newly created file name with path)
```

This will return a **Bitmap**

For more detail see [this link](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/javase/src/com/google/zxing/client/j2se/MatrixToImageWriter.java?r=1096)

Comment: This won't work since `writeToFile()` is not available in the Android Module. Have a look here: http://codeisland.org/2013/generating-qr-codes-with-zxing/